# NPM specify package dependency without version number

Tags: git, github, jenkins, npm, package.json

I have two repos X and Y. Y references X in its package.json for using some modules. X and Y have master branches and both are deployed to common npm-registery(lets call it version 2.0.0). So repo Y references X 2.0.0 in its package.json. All good till here.

Now, the problem --

I have created a new branch in both repos(lets call them bX and bY). These 2 branches are not ready to be merged to the master of their corresponding branches. Hence **I cannot publish a new version of X with bX changes only. Or can I?**

But I want to use the changes I have made in bX to be used in bY.

When I googled around, I found that I can give the url of repo X in Y's package.json like this -- **https://github.com/url-to-repo/X.git#bX** and it works fine in my local system when I built with npm. But when I used it with jenkins build for testing environment, it fails with the following error --

> The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing
>   https://github.com/url-to-repo/X.git/info/refs

And that issue seems to be related to the following --

> Please upgrade your git client. GitHub.com no longer supports git over
>   dumb-http:
>   https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days

I logged into Jenkins server and the git version there is 1.7.2.5 (In GitHub the dump http support is revoked but this won't effect you unless you're running a git version prior to v1.6.6 and fetch using a http remote URL -- from github docs)

So I dont understand what is going wrong here. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Can you use ssh urls?

Comment: Instead of the http urls? I haven't tried. Let me try that now.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot. Could you put this as an answer so I could accept?

Also, is this the actual solution to the problem or a work around?

Comment: Great! I posted my answer. As additional info, could you please tell mei f the GitHub repositories are private or not? Maybe you get 403 because of the authentication. Anyway, I always enjoyed using ssh instead https for git. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to use SSH urls instead of https ones.

So, instead having

```
https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

You will have

```
git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

If you didn't set up your SSH keys on your machine, [here is how to do it](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).